# How to Query Route53 hosted zone to check for an existing record set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I am new to amazon Route53. As of now, I am able to create a hosted zone and a resource record set in my amazon account. But now I want to search whether a record set **already exists** in my hosted zone. For Example

`Hosted zone "abc.com"` and it has two-record set in it.

1. `A.abc.com`
2. `B.abc.com`

Now I want to query my `hosted zone` and find out whether `A.abc.com` **already exists** in the `abc.com`.

So, is there any API that I can use where I can pass my amazon credentials and my amazon `hostedzone` and the searched `"record set"` and then I can get the result back whether that record set already exists. Kindly guide me.

After research, I found out that there is `"ListResourceRecordSet"` which will give me the list back for a particular zone. But I don't want the list I just want to check whether the entry already exists.

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to perform this check efficiently using the `ListResourceRecordSet` API method, and the `name` and `maxitems` parameters. You haven't specified how you are accessing the API, so I'm going to explain this using the standard AWS REST API.

Given your example:

Call the API passing `A.abc.com` as the `name` parameter and `1` as the `maxitems` parameter. Your request will look like this: `https://route53.amazonaws.com/2013-04-01/hostedzone/{YOUR_HOSTED_ZONE_ID}/rrset?name=A.abc.com.&maxitems=1`

Note that I've added a trailing dot (".") to the end of the resource name `A.abc.com.` The [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ListResourceRecordSets.html) indicates that it may affect result sort order so I add it just in case.

You will get back an XML result in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListResourceRecordSetsResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/">
    <ResourceRecordSets>
        <ResourceRecordSet>
            <Name>A.abc.com.</Name>
            <Type>A</Type>
            <TTL>3600</TTL>
            <ResourceRecords>
                <ResourceRecord>
                    <Value>SOME_IP_ADDRESS</Value>
                </ResourceRecord>
            </ResourceRecords>
        </ResourceRecordSet>
    </ResourceRecordSets>
    <IsTruncated>true</IsTruncated>
    <NextRecordName>B.abc.com.</NextRecordName>
    <NextRecordType>A</NextRecordType>
    <MaxItems>1</MaxItems>
</ListResourceRecordSetsResponse>
```

Now you're going to have to do some parsing. Check the result to see if there is one `ResourceRecordSet` and if its `Name` property matches the name of the resource record you are looking for (you probably want to do a case-insensitive compare of the two values). Keep in mind that the `Name` property has that trailing period (".") at the end, so add it to the name you're searching for before doing the comparison.

If there is exactly one resource record set and the name matches the one you are looking for, it exists. If either one of those checks fails, then it does not exist.

Granted, this isn't as simple as a `GetResourceRecordSet` operation would be, but at least it keeps you from having to query the entire zone and parse a bunch of records. You also won't run into the long delay or throttling issues that you may using the CLI `--query` option.

There does not appear to be a way to use this method with the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html) as it lacks a `--name` parameter for some reason. I can vouch for the fact that the [JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Route53.html#listResourceRecordSets-property) will allow you to do this using the `StartRecordName` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to filter the API call, but there is a way to filter the data returned. Using the CLI you can do this with the `--query` option.

[From the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html): *"To view all the resource record sets of a particular name, use the --query parameter to filter them out. For example:"*

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z2LD58HEXAMPLE --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Name == 'A.abc.com']"
```

Comment: Be warned that in large zones, this can take quite a while and you may even receive throttling errors. I'm a bit surprised why there aren't more granular queries.